# Rails - select_tag / chechbox tag issue - can't get array of IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I've got a list of products in a form that's for another resource that I want to submit.  It works without using the label tag, but I want the label tag working.

```
                    <%= label_tag "product_ids[#{product.id}]" do %>
                      <%= check_box_tag "product_ids[#{product.id}]" %>
                      <%= product.name %>
                    <% end %>
```

This produces the following output:

```
"product_ids"=>{"2"=>"1", "6"=>"1", "3"=>"1"}
```

Is it possible to just get the array of IDs and not the hash?

Answer (score 0):

Change for

```
<%= check_box_tag "product_ids[]", nil, nil, id: "product_ids[#{product.id}]"  %>
```

And get `params['product_ids[]']`

Try that way?

Comment: Thanks but - this breaks the label, and clicking on the name no longer selects the checkbox.  If I change the label to the same, the no matter which label you click, only the first checkbox is toggled.

Comment: I get it, let me think, we need same ids on label and input, but  in input we need different id and name, right??

Comment: Edited, try pls, im not sure @fatfrog